# Sort items inside my React.Js SPFx web part

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript, reactjs

I have a SharePoint list, and i want to order the items based on the "Featured" field, but things is not working, where if i define this ordering logic:-

```
a.map(b => {
            if (b === 'Home Page Feature 1') {
                this.orderedFeaturedNews.splice(1, 0, b);
            } else if (b === 'Home Page Feature 2') {
                this.orderedFeaturedNews.splice(2, 0, b);
            } else if (b === 'Home Page Feature 3') {
                this.orderedFeaturedNews.splice(3, 0, b);
            }
        });
```

nothing will be shown...and i will only get result if  define `else` as follow:-

```
a.map(b => {
            if (b === 'Home Page Feature 1') {
                this.orderedFeaturedNews.splice(1, 0, b);
            } else if (b === 'Home Page Feature 2') {
                this.orderedFeaturedNews.splice(2, 0, b);
            } else  {
                this.orderedFeaturedNews.splice(3, 0, b);
            }
        });
```

so can anyone advice why the above is not working?

Here is the full code:-

Here is a screenshot of the SharePoint list:-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer here is that you shouldn't use `map` to *sort*.  You should use `sort`. Secondly, you are not using `map` here the way it should be used. You *should* use `map` to create a new array - the callback function used by `map` should `return` something that populates the new array:

```
const newArray = oldArray.map(thing => {
    // do something with 'thing', but then:
    return somethingElse
})
```

The way you are using `map`, to just iterate over the items in an array, you should really be accomplishing by using `forEach`, which does just that: iterate over the items in an array *without the expectation of having something returned with which to create a new array*.

[More documentation about `map`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[More documentation about `forEach`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

You are also using `map` incorrectly at the beginning of your `getFeaturedNews` function where you are iterating over your `news` array in `state` and then conditionally pushing items into a new array.  If you want to conditionally add items to a new array based on meeting certain conditions, you should use `filter`.

[More documentation on `filter`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

And then just after that use of `map`, where you do actually use `filter`, the `filter` at that point is redundant because everything in `this.featuredNews` *already* has `item.Featured` with a truthy (i.e. filled in, not blank) value because of your conditional in the `map`.

That all being said about the proper use of `map` vs. `forEach` vs. `filter`, still, if your ultimate goal is to sort the items, you should use `sort`.

[More documentation on `sort`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

In this case, since you are comparing strings whose only difference is the final number, you can use a handy little string function called `localeCompare` to help you sort the items. [The documentation for `localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) says:

> The localeCompare() method returns a number indicating whether a
> reference string comes before, or after, or is the same as the given
> string in sort order.

So `localeCompare` used in a `sort` will "alphabetize" the strings.

So in your case, you could do something like this:

```
private getFeaturedNews() {

    const { news } = this.state;

    this.featuredNews = news.filter(newsItem => newsItem.Featured);

    // sort will sort the elemenst _in place_,
    // you do not need to create a new array
    this.featuredNews.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.Featured.localeCompare(b.Featured);
    });

    console.log('this.featuredNews is in order:')
    console.log(this.featuredNews);
}
```

Comment: your code worked for me .. thanks